# Invalid token format in Google API

Tags: php, mysql, google-api, google-plus, google-api-client

there i found some error, when i want to make sure the session on Login with google account. And the error is  :

Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid token format in C:\xampp\htdocs\google\googleAPI\src\Google\Client.php:434 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\google\callback.php(5): Google_Client->setAccessToken(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\google\googleAPI\src\Google\Client.php on line 434

and then this is my code :

```
<?php   
require_once('config.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])){
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
}
else if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $token;


}
else{
    header("location: index.php");
}

$oAtuth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$user = $oAtuth->userinfo->get();

echo "<pre>";

print_r($user);

?>
```

Please tell me whats wrong with this code

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['accessToken'])` to see the contents. The error says it is an array. The method likely expects a string. My guess is it's an array with accessToken and refreshToken, and you only need the accessToken. (Just a guess, please provide the dump.)

Comment: @Tobias : Provide the dump in every statement of $_SESSION['accessToken'] ?

Comment: Just in the line above where the error occurs should suffice.

Comment: Okey just in line 5. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: This will not solve your issue, it's just to inspect the variable to debug. Please post it (edit your question) if you still need help.

Comment: Okay , i will inform you soon

Comment: @TobiasK : its work thank youuu

Comment: Can you write an answer then what you changed? Was it just that you had to access an array index?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong value of token in `$_SESSION['accessToken']`.

Comment: Dear Zen, what's the correct answer with the wrong value of token? Can you tell me